# How do I set the arguments for an r:get call of the R extension using a slider?

Tags: r, netlogo

I want to set the xy coordinates of netlogo turtles following a beta distribution from R, obtained via the R extension:

```
  extensions [r]
  create-turtles 1000 [
    set color red
    set shape "circle"
    setxy r:get "rbeta(1,2,3)*100" r:get "rbeta(1,2,3)*100"
  ]
```

The call to `rbeta ( )` is given as a string within the NetLogo code. How do you write it so that the parameters for `rbeta( )` in the `r:get` call can be set via a global variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `word` to concatenate your slider values and your function call string. For the example below, you would just replace the temporary `s1` and `s2` variables with your slider variables:

```
extensions [r]

to setup
  ca

  let s1 2
  let s2 3

  crt 10 [
    set shape "circle"
    let betaCall ( word "rbeta(1," s1 ", " s2" ) * 100") 
    setxy r:get betaCall r:get betaCall
  ]
  reset-ticks
end
```